# Initialize container in static constructor

Tags: c#, simple-injector

Is it legit to initialize the simple injector container in a static constructor?

Example:

```
using SimpleInjector;

public static Bootstrapper
{
    private readonly static Container container;

    static Bootstrapper()
    {
        Bootstrapper.container = new Container();
    }
}
```

Comment: Exposing the Container as public static filed scares me. Are you using container as Service Locator?

Comment: For the sake of technicality and clarity, I'll make it `private` in my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @NedStoyanov said, a static constructor gives guarantees about uniqueness, so this can be beneficial. The downside of static constructors however is that they are usually more difficult to debug and any exception thrown from the body of the cctor is wrapped in an InitializationException, which makes it harder to see the actual problem.

I also want to repeat @WSriramSakthivel's warning: Although having the `Container` declared as `public readonly static` field in your composition root, prevent accessing this field from *outside* the composition root, whenever possible. Using it from outside the composition root means applying the [Service Locator anti-pattern](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorisanAnti-Pattern/).

Do note that the use of a cctor to initialize your container can have downsides as well. When verifying your container in integration tests, and running some integration tests that use the container to build object graphs, you often want to let each test have its own container instance with its own slightly different configuration. This is something that you won't get working when using a cctor.

So long story short, although using a cctor might be fine and gives some nice guarantees, I think in most cases, it will only be in the way.

Answer (score 2):

In my experience, you should try to avoid static instances in most of the cases. Imagine this, the lifetime of the **container** matches the lifetime of the application. In other words, if you make the **container** static, it will stay alive until the application is closed.

For a better practice, find the entry point of your application. Let's assume it is **static void Main()**. In this case, create an instance of the container here and create startup objects (Windows, Forms, etc.) using this container.

If you design your DI correctly, you should not need the **container** object later on in the application. Just make sure the services (that are registered with **container**) are injected via constructors into objects when needed.

Also, check out [Service Locator violates SOLID by Mark Seemann](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/05/15/service-locator-violates-solid/). Mark has plenty of posts on DI and explaining why this is a bad practice.

Comment: "If you design your DI correctly, you should not need the container object later on in the application." I agree, but my question isn't about design principles. I was just curious if it's technically legit (because perhaps the initialization of the container needs to happen after all static constructors in the assembly are called? I don't know the technical details, hence my question :)

Comment: The container doesn't know anything about your application-specific classes and their static constructors. So it is *possible* to initialize it in a static constructor. It is not necessarily the best thing to do, though. @decyclone did a good job explaining why.

Answer (score 1):

Should be ok, the `static` constructor is guaranteed to be invoked only once before the type is first used and is thread safe.

From the speicification

> Static constructors are not inherited, and cannot be called directly. 
>   The static constructor for a closed class type executes at most once in a given application domain.
>
> The execution of a static constructor is triggered by the first of the following events to occur within an application domain:
>   •   An instance of the class type is created.
>   •   Any of the static members of the class type are referenced.